# Return from Try/Catch block in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, exception, try-catch

Kotlin newbie here...

So I have a method that returns a userDefined object

```
fun doSomethingMagical(param1: String): UserDefinedObject {
     val result = UserDefinedObject
     // execute some code 
     try {
       ....
       if(some expression){
        val temp = //some code
        result = temp
      }
       return result
     } catch(e : Exception){
     null
     }
}
```

the above method gives me 2 error:

**Variable 'result' must be initialized**

**A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')**

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Some thoughts:  you don’t provide enough code for someone to determine where UserDefinedObject is defined, you can’t reassign the value of result as you already declared it as a val and you need to return a UserDefinedObject in the catch case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution, probably not the best one though:

```
fun doSomethingMagical(param1: String): UserDefinedObject? {
 var result = UserDefinedObject() 
 //assuming this object has no properties
 //if it does you much provide them to initialize it
 ...
 try {
   ....
   if(some expression){
    val temp : UserDefinedObject = //some code
    result = temp
 } catch(e : Exception){
    return null
 }
  return result
}
```

A better one, depending on whether or not you need the result before the try (I'm assuming you don't), you may be able to do it this way:

```
fun doSomethingMagical(param1: String): UserDefinedObject? {
   return try {
     whateverSomeCodeIs() // returns a UserDefinedObject
  } catch(e : Exception){
    null
  }
}
```

Or this way:

```
fun doSomethingMagical(param1: String): UserDefinedObject? {
       try {
         return whateverSomeCodeIs() // returns a UserDefinedObject
      } catch(e : Exception){
        return null
      }
    }
```

Or this way which will imply the return type and doesn't require "return" explicitly:

```
fun doSomethingMagical(param1: String) = try { whateverSomeCodeIs() } catch(e: Exception) { null }
```

If you don't want it to be nullable (which is what the "?" indicates) then you would need to return a UserDefinedObject in the catch, allow the exception to be thrown and catch it later, or ensure that an exception can not be thrown.

I'd also recommend that you check out the Kotlin docs. They are pretty informative. Here's a link to their [Exceptions section](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exceptions.html).

Comment: Honestly I think one of the biggest problems with the Kotlin docs is they often assume you're familiar with Java - if you're new to coding and you don't know what an exception or try/catch *is* then they're kinda low on info! Probably worth reading the Java docs for an overview: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html

Answer (score 0):

So a bit of background - a `try` block is what you wrap some code in when that code might `throw` an `Exception`, which you can think of as a kind of error. If an exception is ever thrown, *execution of that code stops* and the program starts to back out of the chain of functions it called to get where it is. If nothing `catch`es that exception, it'll eventually crash the program.

So to be safe, you can wrap code in a `try` block (which implies that it could throw) and add a `catch` block to deal with the expected exception. If an exception gets thrown, it backs out of the `try` block, but if there's a `catch` that handles that exception type, it jumps to that block and carries on executing from there - it's handled, everything can continue!

For example, if you wanted to read from a file, there's a possibility of a problem where it's just not available for some reason, and the reading code could throw an `IOException`. You'd `catch` that exception type, and handle the situation gracefully instead of letting it crash, that kind of thing.

So here's the basic flow of your code:

```
fun doSomethingMagical(param1: String): UserDefinedObject {
     val result = UserDefinedObject
     // execute some code 
     try {
       ....
       return result
     } catch(e : Exception){
        null
     }
}
```

What you're basically saying is, you're going to `try` to execute some code, which eventually ends with a `return` statement. But that implies there's a possibility of an exception, ending that block early - you might never hit that `return`. In which case you jump to the `catch` block (which handles all types of `Exception`), do whatever is in there, and then exit the whole *try/catch* and carry on with the rest of the `doSomethingMagical` function.

But if that happens, you never hit a `return`. If an exception is thrown (which you're explicitly saying might happen by using a `try` block - that's you saying you'll handle it) then you won't reach a `return` statement - that's why you're getting error messages like `A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body` or whatever. There's a possible flow of execution that doesn't reach one, and that's not allowed

---

So there's two typical ways to do this - you could either return a value in the `try`, and return a fallback value in the `catch`:

```
try {
    ...
    // return from the function right here
    return result
} catch(e: Exception) {
    // or if there was a problem, return from here
    return fallbackValue
}
```

or just initialise a mutable `var` with the default value, return it at the end of the function, and maybe change it inside the `try` (if that succeeds):

```
var result = someDefaultValue
try {
    // do things, set new result
    result = somethingElse
} catch (e: Exception) {
    // whatever handling you need to do, having this here ensures code execution
    // continues if there's any problem in the try block
}
// whatever the value of result is (default or if it's been changed), return it here
return result
```

And the latter looks like what you're going for since you're initialising a `result` value at the start of the function (can't be a `val` if you want to change it though)